# Why did totem stop supporting DLNA?

Tags: totem, dlna

Argh, I’ve been watching all my videos over my network for years, now what do I do?

Seems like a backwards move, as even my new TV can now play video off my dlna server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [commit where the plugin was removed](http://git.gnome.org/browse/totem/commit/?id=adc3ba965ab46a94335ffee06dacdad24322a093), it seems that it was removed because no one was maintaining it.  It had remained in tree but disabled for a while, according to the relevant `configure` script bits that were removed in this commit:

```
diff --git a/configure.in b/configure.in
index 9577162..178976d 100644
--- a/configure.in
+++ b/configure.in
@@ -389,11 +389,6 @@ for plugin in ${used_plugins}; do
    add_plugin="1"

    case ${plugin} in
-       coherence_upnp)
-           # The Coherence framework still uses PyGTK, and thus conflicts with the new pygobject introspected bindings
-           plugin_error_or_ignore "the coherence_upnp plugin uses PyGTK and conflicts with the new pygobject bindings"
-           add_plugin="0"
-       ;;
        gromit)
            if test "${have_x11}" != "yes" ; then
                plugin_error_or_ignore "the gromit plugin is not supported on non-X11 targets"
```

Since no one stepped up to port the plugin over to the new GObject Introspection based Python bindings that the rest of Totem was using.

It doesn't sound like they saw anything wrong with DLNA, and if someone stood up to maintain and update the plugin they might add the feature back.